# Openlayers,GeoServer,geoExt

Tags: extjs, openlayers, geoserver, geoext

I am developing a WEBGIS Portal for DataSearch.

I have published the shapefile through Geoserver, Openlayer and geoExt but I am not able to query the with my data either by wfs, gml or json. I think I am not able to establish the connection between the file and my webpage as I am not able to collect the Information in my gridpanel after entering the name.

This is the link to my

[JavaScript](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0lm20kbzxEYQjZXaTV6cEJJanM/edit?usp=sharing) and the [Json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0lm20kbzxEYQVpGOUYwZ0ZaZUE/edit?usp=sharing)

Also if possible can anyone tell me the new link to following url

http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/apps/gaz/index.html

Comment: What information does that URL you say contain? Is it geoserver documentation? You can find it in www.geoserver.org

As for the problem itself, would you mind explaining what's your exact problem? It seems that you receive the JSON without problems, so is it when adding that info to a GridPanel?

Comment: JavaScript is the Code which i Have Used and Json is the Json file which is used in that code for the Retrieval of Data. I do not know why my WFS is not working that is why i try to use the Json.And My requested Geoserver URL is giving me the correct answer in URL But is not connecting to my code, Can you help in getting the Information from the address http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&typename=LULC1&propertyname=NAME

Comment: Could you specify the error you get when requesting the Features through your webapp?

Comment: TypeError: this.featureType is null                               while requesting the WFS

Comment: Do you have more than one instance of Geoserver running? Are you sure this is the correct NS? featureNS:"http://localhost:8081/geoserver/Final"
Port 8081 instead of the 8080 you use in the rest

Comment: yes I have used "localhost:8081/geoserver/Final" as my FeatureNS and and "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&typename=LULC1&propertyname=NAME" is my geoserver Path of my feature. is it the problem